# Make an Example and shaded box like in the book

Tags: boxes, examples

I want to make Examples in the book as in the following book

http://www.analogmachine.org/Books/Chapter1.pdf

See Page 2...

Also shaded box as in the page 3... Pictures can be seen below.

[image: Shaded Box 1]

[image: Shaded Box 2]

---

Minimal Code for the First part of the Question.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsthm,color}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{exinn}{Example}[chapter]
\newenvironment{example}
  {\clubpenalty=10000
   \begin{exinn}%
   \mbox{}%
   {\color{blue}\leaders\hrule height .8ex depth \dimexpr-.8ex+0.8pt\relax\hfill}%
   \mbox{}\linebreak\ignorespaces}
  {\par\kern2ex\hrule\end{exinn}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter One}
\section{Section One}

\begin{example}
    What is $a^2 - b^2$?

$a^2 - b^2 = (a - b) \times (a + b)$
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) I think it would be better if you split your question in two because this site works best if you ask one question at the time. Also please provide screenshots of the entities you want to produce.

Comment: In my eyes these both questions are ok for on post … I added an example as answer but in the future it would be good if you try it yourself first an then post your code. Otherwise it looks like _„I need XXX build it for me!”_ which is not relay nice ;-) Furthermore a better title is recommended, like “Framed boxes width round corners or tile on the frame” …

Comment: Is the source code for this book available somewhere?

Answer (score 17):

> **Update**
>   I included @Marco’s code (setting the title with `frametitlefont` to be able to add an extra headline to each environment) and implemented an unnumbered version for examples (`example*`)

Have a look at the [`mdframed` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% EXAMPLES
%% set the counter for your environment
\newcounter{example}
\renewcommand{\theexample}{\thesection.\arabic{example}}

%% define the style
\mdfdefinestyle{example}{%
    linecolor=blue,
    outerlinewidth=2pt,
    bottomline=false,
    leftline=false,rightline=false,
    skipabove=\baselineskip,
    skipbelow=\baselineskip,
    frametitle=\mbox{},
}
%% setup the environments
%%% with number
\newmdenv[%
    style=example,
    settings={\global\refstepcounter{example}},
    frametitlefont={\bfseries Example~\theexample\quad},
]{example}
%%% without number (starred version)
\newmdenv[%
    style=example,
    frametitlefont={\bfseries Example~\quad},
]{example*}

% BOXES
%% set up the environment
\newmdenv[%
    backgroundcolor=red!8,
    linecolor=red,
    outerlinewidth=1pt,
    roundcorner=5mm,
    skipabove=\baselineskip,
    skipbelow=\baselineskip,
]{boxed}

% for testing
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\section{Section One}
\blindtext
\begin{example}[frametitle=Some Headlinetext]
    \blindtext
\end{example}
\blindtext
\begin{example*}[frametitle=Foobar baz]
    \blindtext
\end{example*}
\blindtext
\begin{example}
    \blindtext
\end{example}
\blindtext
\begin{boxed}
    \blindtext
\end{boxed}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

The manual shows an example putting the title on the frame …

Comment: Any way to get some kind of table of examples with this too? That would be insane!

Comment: @BennX: Sure … one can setup a new list for the examples. If you make a new (follow-up) question and link it here I’ll show you how. I don’t want to add it here to keep the code clean …

Comment: Wrote the question. Thanks for your help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/262915/how-to-create-a-list-for-mdframed-example-boxs

Answer (score 10):

***TIKZ MWE:***

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\newcommand{\mybox}[2]{%
         \begin{center}%
            \begin{tikzpicture}%
                \node[rectangle, draw=#2, top color=#2!10, bottom color=#2!90, rounded corners=5pt, inner xsep=5pt, inner ysep=6pt, outer ysep=10pt]{
                \begin{minipage}{0.75\linewidth}#1\end{minipage}};%
            \end{tikzpicture}%
         \end{center}%
}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\mybox{\blindtext}{green}
\blindtext
\mybox{\blindtext}{red}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Marco Daniel how can we change the colour at the very next paragraph? I mean i want to have a green backround here and a pink after that. How can we do this possible??

Comment: @Giannis I updated the code with your request.

Answer (score 3):

This partially answers your first question:

```
\usepackage{amsthm,color}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{exinn}{Example}[chapter]
\newenvironment{example}
  {\clubpenalty=10000
   \begin{exinn}%
   \mbox{}%
   {\color{blue}\leaders\hrule height .8ex depth \dimexpr-.8ex+0.8pt\relax\hfill}%
   \mbox{}\linebreak\ignorespaces}
  {\par\kern2ex\hrule\end{exinn}}
```

It's not difficult to change the font in the heading.

Answer (score 3):

We can use the package [`tcolorbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) by Thomas F. Sturm.

Comment: Probably the best option see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44840/963