# mdframed theorems within beamerarticle script

Tags: beamer, theorems, mdframed, beamerarticle

I need to use framed theorem environments the way they are made in [Make an Example and shaded box like in the book](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38354/make-an-example-and-shaded-box-like-in-the-book).
The realization with `\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}` is working fine.
But now, I have to implement this in a ready written script being made with `\documentclass{article}` and `\usepackage{beamerarticle}`.
The predefined theorem environments in german language `Satz`, `Beispiel` and so on are used. I already tried using `\setbeamertemplate{theorem begin}{...}` and `\setbeamertemplate{theorem end}{...}` for inserting those boxing commands for example with

```
\setbeamertemplate{theorem begin}{\begin{mdframed}%
[linecolor=yellow,outerlinewidth=3pt,backgroundcolor=red!10,roundcorner=15pt,%
skipabove=\baselineskip,skipbelow=\baselineskip]}%
\setbeamertemplate{theorem end}{\end{mdframed}}
```

but it is not working.
Are there other ways, as I do not want to rename all used environment and make new ones?

I found a solution

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{Satz}{\begin{mdframed}[linecolor=yellow,outerlinewidth=3pt,backgroundcolor=red!10,roundcorner=15pt,%
skipabove=\baselineskip,skipbelow=\baselineskip]\vspace{-0.5cm}}
\AfterEndEnvironment{Satz}{\end{mdframed}}
```

but others are still welcome.

Comment: You know me (HSU) - I am the author of mdframed.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel - Yes, indeed - I know you... Do you have a solution? I'll edit the question next minute, as I found one way - but I'm looking for others, too. Best wishes.

Comment: At the moment I can't test you know my job. At the evening I will have a look.

Comment: If all else fails, you can use the `notheorems` option to beamerarticle and define the environments Satz,... entirely yourself. Not nice, but at least you won't have to go though the entire source.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz, of course this might be done - but I prefer the `etoolbox`-way.. or another better one - which might come soon here, hopefully. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution with `\setbeamertemplate{begin theorem}` doesn't work because it isn't defined.
The file `beamerbasetheorems.sty` loaded by `beamerarticle` provides the definition of the theorem environments.

```
\mode
<article>
{
  \ifbeamer@ams
    \RequirePackage{amsmath}
    \RequirePackage{amsthm}

    \renewenvironment<>{proof}[1][\proofname]
    {\begin{actionenv}#2\begin{originalproof}[{#1}]}{\end{originalproof}\end{actionenv}}

    % Make new theorem overlay-specification-aware
    \let\beamer@origthm=\@thm
    \def\@thm#1#2#3{\def\beamer@store{{#1}{#2}{#3}}\beamer@readspec}
    \def\beamer@storeaction{\begin{actionenv}}
    \newcommand<>\beamer@readspec[1][]{\def\beamer@storeaction{\begin{actionenv}#2}%
      \expandafter\beamer@origthm\beamer@store[{#1}]}

    \let\beamer@origbegintheorem=\@begintheorem
    \def\@begintheorem{\beamer@storeaction\beamer@origbegintheorem}

    \let\beamer@origendtheorem=\@endtheorem
    \def\@endtheorem{\beamer@origendtheorem\end{actionenv}}
  \fi

  \def\th@example{\th@remark}

  \newcommand{\ExampleInline}[1]{\translate{Example}: \ignorespaces#1}

  % Compatiblity:
  \newcommand{\BeispielInline}[1]{Beispiel: \ignorespaces#1}
}
```

You see there are no definition. The environments `lemma` etc. are also defined in the quoted file.

Based on this information I prefer the solution with `etoolbox` (loaded by `mdframed`). To modify every theorem environment you can also use `\BeforeBeginEnvironment{\@begintheorem}{...}`.

To verify my answer you can test the simple example:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{book}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\setbeamertemplate{theorem begin}{\undefined \fooo}
\begin{document}
Text
\begin{theorem}
foo bar
\end{theorem}
Text
\begin{lemma}
foo bar
\end{lemma}
\end{document}
```

The setting `\setbeamertemplate{theorem begin}{\undefined \fooo}` has no influence.

Comment: I hope it helps.

Comment: yes it does and the idea with `\BeforeBeginEnvironment{\@begintheorem}{...}` is great. THX: Merry Xmas and have a happy new year!