# Math inside tables and formatting

Tags: math-mode, tables, horizontal-alignment, formatting, colortbl

I'm trying to make a little summary of mathematic analysis, useful for my university, in LaTeX. I'm stuck in the problem of creating nice table, with alternate colouring containing equations with various alignments.

I succeeded in building such a table only with `displaymath` inside a `\parbox`, which doesn't allow equation alignments, but not with `align*`.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \lipsum[1-3]
    % Row color alternating
    \rowcolors{1}{gray!25}{white}
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        \hline
        \parbox{\linewidth}{$$f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{Q}$$}\\
        \parbox{\linewidth}{$$g : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{C}$$}\\
        \parbox{\linewidth}{$$h : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{Q}$$}\\
        $f(g(x)) = \frac{\pi}{2}$\
        % This doesn't work
        %\begin{align*}&f(g(x)) = \frac{\pi}{2}&&\forall x > 0\end{align*}\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \lipsum[4-6]
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: See [Why is `\[`...`\]` preferable to `$$`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5764) for some advice on math notation and use.

Comment: Tnx a lot, very useful, I'm pretty new in latex

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are perhaps many ways of doing this. However, requiring a table structure with alternating row colours limits your possibilities. Here is a mock-up of your current document with some alterations:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{multicol}% http://ctan.org/pkg/multicol
\usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\usepackage{amsfonts}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsfonts
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}% Increase the row height of tabular/array
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash$}p{\linewidth}<{$}}
\begin{document}
  \begin{multicols}{2}
    \lipsum[1-5] \par \medskip

    % Row color alternating
    \rowcolors{1}{gray!25}{white}%
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}%
    \noindent\begin{tabular}{C}
      \hline
      f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{Q} \\
      g : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{C} \\
      h : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{Q} \\
      f(g(x)) = \frac{\pi}{2}\phantom{\ \forall x > 0} \\
      f(g(x)) = \frac{\pi}{2}\ \forall x > 0 \\
      \hline
    \end{tabular} \par \medskip

    \lipsum[6-8]
  \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Here are some comments pertaining to the adjusted example:

- I've used [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) to adjust the margins, since the default margin setup in two-column mode I find too narrow;
- The table is set apart from the flowing text using `\par\medskip` to introduce a medium vertical skip as a separation;
- Since the `tabular` is an element (in horizontal mode) on its own, it starts a paragraph and is therefore indented by `\parindent`. Using `\noindent` removes this indentation, setting is flush left with the column margin;
- A single column of width `\linewidth` makes the `tabular` stretch the entire width of the column (`\columnwidth` would have worked just as well);
- Left- and right-column padding is removed via `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}`;
- `tabular` row height is increased by a factor of 50% via `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}`;
- Although the single `tabular` is set in paragraph style (`p{\linewidth}`), the [`array` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/array) column specification allows for inserting `<stuff>` before each column entry using `>{<stuff>}` and appending afterwards using `<{<stuff>}`. Therefore,

  ```
  \newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash$}p{\linewidth}<{$}}
  ```

  defines a new column type `C` that centres its contents (`\centering`) in math mode `$`...`$`.
- Horizontal alignment with other row elements is possible via ample use of `\phantom{...}`, since using `align` environments do not work across the `tabular` rows.

Comment: First thanks, there are a lot of things I didn't know, I improved and cleaned my pages! I modified the column type definition without centering and without inline math `\newcolumntype{C}{ >{\arraybackslash$\displaystyle} p{\linewidth} <{$} }` and the row height `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5}`. But now the eqns are aligned to the bottom, they should be aligned in the middle of the row. I did a quick search with no luck...

Answer (score 19):

I would rather forget about stripes, they are really meant to be left to zebras and not mathematical books and they do not enhance readability as is sometimes claimed (see link in comments). If you want to have a bit more of a modern look and similar to what you want, use the excellent `tcolorbox` package by Prof. Thomas F. Sturm, author of
LATEX – *Einführung in das Textsatzsystem*   who also now kindly provided documentation in English.

[image]

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[listings,theorems]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{before={\par\medskip\pagebreak[0]\noindent},after={\par\medskip}}%
\begin{document}
\section{Table of Equations}
\newcounter{texercise}[section]
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=blue!5,colframe=blue!50!black,arc=0mm,
theorem={Equation}{texercise}{Summation}{myMarker}]{Summation of Numbers}{summation}
  For all natural number $n$ it holds:\\[2mm]
  \[\displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}\]
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=blue!5,colframe=blue!50!black,arc=0mm,
theorem={Equations}{texercise}{More on summation}{myMarker}]{Summation of Numbers}{summation}
  For all natural number $n$ it holds:\\[2mm]
   \[\displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}\]
  \[\displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}+ \frac{n(n+1)}{2}\]
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

You can include any material in the boxes, provided by `tcolorbox`, including tabulars.

[image]

```
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=blue!5,colframe=blue!50!black,arc=0mm,
theorem={Equations}{texercise}{More on summation}{myMarker}]{Summation of Numbers}{summation}
\medskip

\begin{tabular}{lr@{~}c@{~}l@{\qquad}r}
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\hspace{-2ex}\textbf{Line Values.}} \\
\multicolumn{5}{r}{}\\
\multicolumn{4}{l}{Altitude of triangle on side $a$,} \\
& $h$ &=& \( \displaystyle \frac{2}{a}
             \sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)} \) & \\
%
\multicolumn{4}{l}{Median of triangle on side $a$,} \\
& $m$ &=& \( \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{2(b^2+c^2) - a^2} \) & \ \\
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\hspace{-2ex}\textbf{Areas.}} \\
%
Rectangle,     & $S$ &=& $b\times h$ &  \\
Square,         & $S$ &=& $b^2$        &  \\
\end{tabular}
\end{tcolorbox}
```

The package has many options and one needs to study the documentation carefully. The English documentation has only been recently added, so you might need to update your distribution.

Comment: That's very interesting, I'll take a deep look. But I think zebras are better because I want to compile a table of notable integrals, with lot of rows, and I think alternating colour should improve readability.

Comment: @ColOfAbRiX Zebras and readability http://www.alistapart.com/d/zebrastripingdoesithelp/zebra_striping_paper_21.pdf, but nature and the army knew all that long ago, as zebras use zebras for camouflage:)

Comment: Well, but zebras aren´t to be printed on paper...