# Adding box filled with color and placing large text inside it

Tags: header-footer, color

I am trying to prepare a class for my college magazine and articles. I would like to know how to place a black box on the top margin of the first page and write some huge text inside it in white color. Present style of the document looks like this,

```
% DOCUMENT LAYOUT
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=5cm,right=2.5cm,top=5cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{wasysym}
% DOCUMENT LAYOUT
\setlength\parindent{0cm}
\usepackage[libertine={Ligatures=TeX,Numbers=OldStyle}]{libertineotf}
\setsansfont{Segoe UI}
% FONTS
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

% ---- CUSTOM COMMANDS
\chardef\&="E050
\newcommand{\html}[1]{\href{#1}{\scriptsize\textsc{[html]}}}
\newcommand{\pdf}[1]{\href{#1}{\scriptsize\textsc{[pdf]}}}
\newcommand{\doi}[1]{\href{#1}{\scriptsize\textsc{[doi]}}}
% ---- MARGIN YEARS
\usepackage{marginnote}
\newcommand{\amper{}}{\chardef\amper="E0BD }
\newcommand{\sides}[1]{\marginnote{\color{MidnightBlue}\sffamily #1}}
%\newcommand{\years}[1]{\marginnote{\footnotesize #1}}
%\renewcommand*{\raggedleftmarginnote}{}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{0.5cm}
\reversemarginpar

% HEADINGS
\usepackage{sectsty} 
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} 
\sectionfont{\mdseries\upshape\Large}
\subsectionfont{\mdseries\scshape\normalsize} 
\subsubsectionfont{\mdseries\upshape\large}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
% PDF SETUP
\usepackage[bookmarks, colorlinks, breaklinks, 
    pdftitle={Here there},
    pdfauthor={My name},
    pdfproducer={}
]{hyperref}  
\hypersetup{linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,filecolor=black,urlcolor=MidnightBlue}
% DOCUMENT
\begin{document}
{\LARGE Effect of aspect ratio and others on others and ourselves}\\[3pt]
\textit{Me myself \& You}. Corr. author : \href{mailto:s.sssss@gmail.com}{\textit{s.sssss@gmail.com}}\\
\textit{Department of Mechanical Engineering.}\\[0.5cm]
{\large \bf Abstract}\\[4pt]
\lipsum[25]
{\section*{Introduction}}
\sides{I am hoping to create some proper paper using this template when i do my masters.}
\lipsum
\sides{How does a para look with this on sides. For a moment i thought it is gone}
\lipsum

%\vspace{1cm}
\vfill{}
%\hrulefill

\end{document}
```

Can some one suggest how to do this?
I want something like the one on the right.
[image]

Comment: Are the positions of the text always equal?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Equal as in? I just want something similar to the photo shown where i can place a black box on top and white text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a problem with `xcolor`. You need to use the option `dvipsnames` to use the color MidnightBlue. You don't need to load `color`  because `xcolor` loads `color`. `pgfplots` loads `tikz` and  you need to load `xcolor` before  pgfplots.

You need to compile twice the next code. I used tikz to place a ablack rectangle on the first page.

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode   
  % DOCUMENT LAYOUT
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=5cm,right=2.5cm,top=5cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{wasysym}
% DOCUMENT LAYOUT
\setlength\parindent{0cm}
\usepackage[libertine={Ligatures=TeX,Numbers=OldStyle}]{libertineotf}
%\setsansfont{Segoe UI} 
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} 
% FONTS
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepackage{eso-pic}

% ---- CUSTOM COMMANDS
\chardef\&="E050
\newcommand{\html}[1]{\href{#1}{\scriptsize\textsc{[html]}}}
\newcommand{\pdf}[1]{\href{#1}{\scriptsize\textsc{[pdf]}}}
\newcommand{\doi}[1]{\href{#1}{\scriptsize\textsc{[doi]}}}
% ---- MARGIN YEARS
\usepackage{marginnote}
\newcommand{\amper{}}{\chardef\amper="E0BD }
\newcommand{\sides}[1]{\marginnote{\color{MidnightBlue}\sffamily #1}}
%\newcommand{\years}[1]{\marginnote{\footnotesize #1}}
%\renewcommand*{\raggedleftmarginnote}{}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{0.5cm}
\reversemarginpar

% HEADINGS
\usepackage{sectsty} 
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} 
\sectionfont{\mdseries\upshape\Large}
\subsectionfont{\mdseries\scshape\normalsize} 
\subsubsectionfont{\mdseries\upshape\large}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{tikz}
% PDF SETUP
\usepackage[bookmarks, colorlinks, breaklinks, 
    pdftitle={Here there},
    pdfauthor={My name},
    pdfproducer={}
]{hyperref}  
\hypersetup{linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,filecolor=black,urlcolor=MidnightBlue}
% DOCUMENT 


\begin{document}
  \thispagestyle{empty} 
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node[anchor=north west,minimum width=21cm,minimum height=8cm,fill=black,text=white] (RB) at (current page.north west){\Huge TITLE};
\node[text=white,text width=4cm,anchor=north west] at ([shift={(3cm,2cm)}]RB.south west){\emph{Petit texte afin de tester la métode. Petit texte afin de tester la métode. Petit texte afin de tester la métode.}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace*{10cm}
\lipsum[1]
\newpage 
{\LARGE Effect of aspect ratio and others on others and ourselves}\\[3pt]
\textit{Me myself \& You}. Corr. author : \href{mailto:s.sssss@gmail.com}{\textit{s.sssss@gmail.com}}\\
\textit{Department of Mechanical Engineering.}\\[0.5cm]
{\large \bf Abstract}\\[4pt]
\lipsum[25]
{\section*{Introduction}}
\sides{I am hoping to create some proper paper using this template when i do my masters.}
\lipsum
\sides{How does a para look with this on sides. For a moment i thought it is gone}
\lipsum

%\vspace{1cm}
\vfill{}
%\hrulefill

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) to place a `\colorbox` in the header:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=5cm,right=2.5cm,top=5cm,bottom=3cm,headheight=22pt]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{fancyhdr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr
\fancypagestyle{unique}{%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% No header rule
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}%
  \fancyhead[C]{%
    \colorbox{black}{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep}{%
      \color{white}\LARGE Effect of aspect ratio and others on others and ourselves}}%
  }%
}
\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{unique}
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

You can, of course, modify the `unique` page style to your liking. I've only duplicated the `plain` page style and added your required header.

Modifications to the header could include stretching the box to span outside the margin. Here's a quick view on the header changes to incorporate it:

```
\fancypagestyle{unique}{%
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% No header rule
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}%
  \fancyhead[C]{%
    \makebox[\textwidth]{%
      \colorbox{black}{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth+50pt-2\fboxsep}{%
        \color{white}\LARGE Effect of aspect ratio and others on others and ourselves}}%
  }}%
}
```

The above header change pushes the coloured box outward (left and right) by 25 points. It accomplishes this by placing a `50pt` overset coloured box inside a centred `\textwidth` box. This avoids LaTeX complaining about an overfull `\hbox` spanning more than `\textwidth`.

Comment: Can you tell how to extend the black box even to the right and left margins at the top.

Comment: @sgp: Added something to show how to extend the box into the margins.

Answer (score 0):

One:We can use the package `tcolorbox` by Thomas F. Sturm.

See

> [Make an Example and shaded box like in the book](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38354/make-an-example-and-shaded-box-like-in-the-book/45954#45954)

Two: We can use the package **contour**

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\contourlength{1.2pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]

\draw [fill=black](0,0) rectangle (4.5,1);
\node at (0.75,0.5) {\contour{white}{\Large Text!}};
\node [fill=white,inner sep=1pt] at (2.25,0.5) {\Large Text!};
\node [fill=white,rounded corners=2pt,inner sep=1pt] at (3.75,0.5) {\Large Text!};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Three: this may be useful

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\node at (5,5) (p) {B}; 
\draw (p.south) -| ++(2mm,3mm) -| (p.north);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have updated the question with an example. Can you suggest now how to do it?